# Trying to get property 'tags' of non-object in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm getting error Trying to get property `tags` of `non-object` when trying to edit data.

View:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
    <select class="form-control" name="tags_id" id="tags_id">
        <option value="{{ $data->tags_id }}">{{ $data->tag->tags }}</option>
        @foreach ($tag as $item)
            <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->tags }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $tag = Tag::all();
    $data = Post::with('tag')->findOrFail($id);
    return view('post.edit', compact('data', 'tag'));
}
```

Comment: Either `$data->tag->tags` or `$item->tags` is causing the error. I suggest you inspect your `$data` and `$item` variables.

Comment: I have found the error, it is in $data->tag->tags. But I don't know what's wrong

Comment: I want to get field tags on table tag

Comment: If your `Post` model hasMany `Tag` then you need a loop to get all data. Or your `data->tag->tags` is null.